# How to handle unique "pseudo-sequences" in Database when multiple processes?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am using Python 3.10 with the SQLAlchemy ORM and an Oracle Database.

The data definition cannot be changed (requirement).
I have a field with a unique constraint and a "pseudo-sequence", which means that the field is unique and it consists of a number in following form: Year - 2000 + sequence-number.
Examples are 220001, 220002, 220003, etc. It must strictly be increasing without gaps.

For now we set this field like this (assume year does not change):

```
WHILE True
   SELECT max(sequence)
   Add 1 to the current maximum from above
   INSERT new record with this updated value in DB. 
   IF Success or counter > max_tries: break
   ELSE counter = counter + 1
```

Naturally there is a race condition because our webserver runs multiple processes (not threads) (also a requirement).

Right now we try to insert the value multiple times "optimistically", which means, if another record has written the number in the mean time we try the above "algorithm" again. This does not scale that good respecitvely if we get much more traffic in the future, than many retries are necessary and the DB load increases.

Is there another way instead of this optimistic locking with moderate expense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] Just use a normal sequence and if you want to generate the pseudo-sequence then you can calculate if for display purposes.

---

If you have a table with the columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id NUMBER
     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
     CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  dt DATE
     CONSTRAINT table_name__dt__nn NOT NULL
);
```

*Note: `IDENTITY` columns are available from Oracle 12.*

Then you have an incrementing sequence (that you can use as the primary key and for any referential constraints) and a date column.

You can generate your pseudo-sequence (for **display** purposes, rather than as a referential constraint) using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and arithmetic:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) - 2000)*10000
       + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) ORDER BY id)
         AS pseudo_seq
FROM   table_name t
```

---

If you did want to persist the pseudo-sequence values then you can use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ( pseudo_seq NUMBER(8,0) );

MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) - 2000)*10000
         + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) ORDER BY id)
           AS pseudo_seq
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   pseudo_seq = src.pseudo_seq
  WHERE pseudo_seq IS NULL;
```

However, given that the `id` column will be increasing sequentially then that is not necessary and the `pseudo_seq` column can just be dynamically generated.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f907b9d6cd2a019bd1686b7f937a50c8)*